# Water hammer, dripping faucet in bathroom

Tags: bathroom, shower, leak, faucet

So I have a mix of problems that I'm not sure how best to deal with since it could very well be multiple problems or just the one.

We had a plumber replace the tub/shower faucet and the corresponding "insides." Ever since then, when we turn the hot water on, only in that tub, we get water hammering. We called them back to fix it twice, but they didn't and so we gave up. it's just a standard shower/tub unit with the water mixer etc. in the insides of the handle, nothing fancy or complicated.

Lately, we are also getting water dripping from the faucet and shower-head when anyone flushes the toilet. A lot of water, about 1/4 cup. Once the draining stops in a few minutes, then there is no dripping until the next time the toilet is flushed.

The toilet flushing does not induce the water hammer, only turning on the water to hot. If you slowly turn the hot water on, you can avoid the hammering, but everyone gets impatient standing there, slowly turning on the hot water.

We do have very high water pressure in our community and do sometimes keep the wall valves only partially open to reduce the pressure coming to the fixture. So what is the answer? draining the lines? Installing a whole house pressure regulator? Finding a new plumber?

Comment: Adding water hammer dampers may solve your problem. In really old homes I have seen a large 2" pipe tee after the main valve with a stubbed leg verticle for 4-6 feet. This was an early form of damper as it was full of air.

Answer (score 1):

There are alternatives to try first before spending more money. See this link...

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-quiet-noisy-water-pipes.html

If these methods do not work for you install a water hammer arrester.

See... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Z0Tb1SdFGk